# By how many bytes is it possible to exceed an allocated block without getting segmentation fault?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I learned that whenever malloc is called, the actual memory given to the program by the OS is not exactly the requested size, but is rounded up to page size. From what I know, page size is 1024 or 4096.

Based on this logic (and correct me if it's wrong), writing beyond my allocated block won't always cause segmentation fault, as this fault is given by the kernel (which has given me a full page and doesn't care what I do so long as I stay inside of it).

The weird thing is that in the program bellow I requested 8 bytes from malloc, and then wrote 80000 (sizeof(size_t) * 10000) bytes further, without getting segmentation fault. I did get invalid read and write valgrind errors though.

Can someone shed light on the topic?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{

    size_t *ptr = (size_t *)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    size_t forward = 10000;

    ptr += forward; 
    *ptr = 8;
    printf("%lu\n", *ptr);

    ptr -= forward;
    free(ptr);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: There is no way to tell.

Comment: Not getting segfault, and having a valid C program - are two different things. You have a program with invalid memory handling, and Valgrind is telling you that. You have an undefined behavior, which is - as any other type of undefined behavior - cannot be relied on.

Comment: @user253751: There are ways to tell.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not reliably.

Comment: @user253751: [glibc provides `malloc_usable_size`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/malloc_005fusable_005fsize.html), and I believe Windows provides something similar.

Comment: Some comment about your code: there is no need to do `ptr += forward` and `ptr -= forward` just do `ptr[forward] = 8`.

Comment: **By how many bytes is it possible to exceed an allocated block without getting segmentation fault?**  TLDR answer:  ***ZERO***  Just because your process didn't fail immediately with a segmentation fault doesn't mean you didn't corrupt memory and lay land mines that can cause failure at any point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that `malloc` requested just one page from the OS for your allocation, and that the subsequent pages remained unmapped.  That's not necessarily true.  `malloc` will typically request many pages at a time and then use them for later allocations if possible, thus making fewer system calls and reducing that overhead.

So it's likely that the several pages following your allocation are also mapped for your process, which is why you don't get a segfault.  Instead, you overwrote memory that could be in use for something important.

Indeed, it's possible that `malloc` requested a larger chunk before `main` started, for internal C library structures, and that your allocation is just being placed within that chunk. In my test, using `strace` to see the `brk()` system call, this chunk was 33 pages in size (132 kB), and your block is in the first page of that chunk.  So your 80 kB overrun is still within that mapped region.

So the answer to the title question is "it depends on where your block is located within its page, and which surrounding pages happen to be mapped".  These in turn depend on the precise algorithm used by `malloc` and the pattern of other allocations and frees done by your code, or library code, up to that point, none of which you can really predict.   It is possible in principle to find out which pages are mapped (e.g. on Linux by parsing `/proc/self/maps`) but this can change unpredictably as memory is allocated and freed by your code or library functions.  So the practical answer is "you don't know".

Basically, you shouldn't make any assumptions about what will or won't happen when you write outside the boundaries of `malloc`ed memory.  The only time when you can really be assured of getting a segfault is when you `mmap`ed and `mprotect`ed the memory yourself.

Comment: Thanks! You've made this much clearer. The question, was, of course, solely for pedagogic purposes and I don't ever intend to rely on the possibility to write this way.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing two very different things. If you ask `malloc` for 1 byte, it may allocate a 4,096 byte page from the operating system but it may only reserve 16 bytes of that block for this call to `malloc`. The next call to `malloc` may get another 16 bytes from that same 4,096 byte page.

You can't assume that just because you didn't get a segmentation fault that means you only accessed space that the implementation has reserved for your block. You can be writing on top of other objects being used for other purposes.